# Changing the place of equation in Python

Tags: python, variables

I defined the "true" variable summing up all the t, r, u and e integers at the first image. When I wrote t + r + u + e = true, it gave an error but when I changed their places and wrote true = t + r + u + e, it worked.

[ERROR HERE] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/srlWG.png)
[FIXED BUT WHY] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9nm8.png)

Can somebody please explain?

- 100 Days of Code, Day 3, Love Calculator project

Comment: The left side of the `=` sign must have a single variable.  It can't be an _expression_.  That's just how Python syntax works.

Answer (score 1):

Equations and assignment statements look similar but are functionally different and are differentiated with `=` for assignment and `==` for equality statements.

Assignments come in the form `variable = expression` and after the expression is evaluated, its value is assigned to the variable. You are **not equating** `true` with `t + r + u + e`, you are **assigning** the value of `t + r + u + e` to `true`. There is a directionality to this and some programming languages emphasize this by using `<-` instead of `=` (E.g. `True <- t + r + u + e`).

Another good example is what happens when you want to assign one variable's value to another.

```
foo = 1
bar = 2
foo = bar
print(foo)
```

What should this print statement output? Did we assign bar to foo or foo to bar? If you were allowed to write assignment statements in either direction, you introduce this ambiguity.